# How can I check programmatically the status of my task queue in Google Appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, queue

I am firing up a queue to complete some tasks in Python Appengine application. Is there a way to get the status of the queue? I would like to check whether it is still running or has incomplete tasks.

Comment: I worked around it by allowing only 1 Maximum Concurrent task running but still I would be interested in covering this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google just released a new SDK Version 1.7.2 - September 18, 2012 and it looks like you can have it using the [QueueStatistics](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes). From the [release notes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes):

> You can now fetch Task Queue Statistics. This allows you to fetch
>   statistics and information about your task queue from within your
>   application. Statistics include information such as the number of
>   tasks in a queue, how many tasks were executed in the last minute and
>   enforced rate. This is an experimental feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is a task queue link on your appengine console where you can look at the pending tasks, statistics and see what's going on.

Comment: I am interested to call my named queue programmatically and if something is already running, I don't want to add anymore tasks.

Comment: Ah. Well, you can definitely do that from java so I would assume you can from python but I wouldn't know for sure :) sorry.

Comment: @Rick: where in java can you list tasks in a queue and their status?

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you can only do it in the development server in unit tests? I use it for my testing. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/index?com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/dev/QueueStateInfo.html